# MongoDB query on specific child

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've got a document that contains an array of elements. I'd like to find specific entries in that document.

Example entry 1:

```json
{
  "c": [
    {
      "k": "1",
      "v": "1",
    },
    {
      "k": "2",
      "v": "2",
    },
  ]
}
```

Example entry 2:

```json
{
  "c": [
    {
      "k": "1",
      "v": "2",
    },
    {
      "k": "2",
      "v": "1",
    },
  ]
}
```

I'd like to find all entries that have a `k` that is `1`, and a matching `v` that is `1` (here, the first entry matches, but the second one doesn't, because the `v` that has the value of `1` is not the same object as the `k` valued `1`).

So far, I found the query:

```json
{
  "$and": [
    {"c.k": "1"},
    {"c.v": "1"}
  ]
}
```

However, that returns both entries, not just the first one. Is there a way to tell MongoDB that both constraints should apply to the same item in the array, and not just to any item?

Comment: use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) query operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@turiviashal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8987128/turivishal), make use of the `$elemMatch` operator which matches documents with will match all the key conditions in at least one object.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "c": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "k": "1",
          "v": "1",
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_FD31VuDkFz)